# specific dynamic routes in next.js

Tags: next.js

I have a feature in my project where users can create albums, these albums are then rendered on the page and the user can click on them to go to a page showing the details of that album. For this I created an albums folder and page.js, then within the albums folder i created a [albumsId] folder, making it a dynamic route. The issue is users can just go in the browser and search /albums/whateverTheyWant, and this will work even if they don't have an album called whateverTheyWant. I have an api that gets all the user's albums from the database, my idea was to use this in my middleware.js and see if the endpoint the user searched for exists as an album within their document in the DB, but I cant get it to work.

for reference, heres my getUserAlbums api:

```
import { connect } from "@/dbConfig/dbConfig";
import User from "@/models/userModel";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

connect();

export async function GET(request) {
  const token = request.cookies.get("token")?.value || '';
  const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token);
  const email = decodedToken ? decodedToken.email : '';

  try {
    const userEmail = email

    if (!userEmail) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: "No email" }, { status: 400 });
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({ email: userEmail });

    if (!user) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: "User not found" }, { status: 404 });
    }

    const albums = user.albums;

    return NextResponse.json({ albums });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

middleware.js

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { GET as getUserAlbums } from "@/app/api/users/getUserAlbums/route.js";


export async function middleware(request) {
  const path = request.nextUrl.pathname;
  const isPublicPath = path === '/login' || path === '/register' || path === '/';
  const token = request.cookies.get("token")?.value || '';

  const isAlbumPath = path.startsWith('/albums/');

  if (!isPublicPath && !token) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.nextUrl));
  }

  if (isAlbumPath && token) {
    const albumName = path.substring('/albums/'.length);
    const userAlbums = await getUserAlbums(); 

    // Check if the requested album exists in the user's albums
    const albumExists = userAlbums.some(album => album.albumName === albumName);

    if (!albumExists) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/albums', request.nextUrl)); 
    }
  }

  // Allow access to the requested path
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/',
    '/profile/:path*',
    '/login',
    '/register',
    '/albums/:path*', 
    '/chat',
    '/about',
    '/contact',
  ],
};
```

Note: the error i received with the following code was Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'User')
46 | });
47 |

> 48 | const User = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
> 49 |
> 50 | export default User;

Comment: I think that the issue might be coming from that middleware runs at the edge and you don't get the connection to the DB from there. Maybe check on the page for the album instead?

Comment: the issue is from the album page, only the existing albums are rendered, so they wont get the error from trying to access an album on this page. This is why I tried implementing it within my middleware to check if the url contains /albums/ and then whatever following the albums actually exists within their document in the DB, considering whatever comes after that is the albumName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED : Thu Mar 21 2024**

**Problem :**

> *users can just go in the browser and search /albums/whateverTheyWant, and this will work even if they don't have an album called whateverTheyWant.*

**Possible Solution :**

- By checking if album ID exists in DB through middleware will cause an extra call *(1. check, 2. return Found or Not Found)*.
- Instead, **on album details page,** `/albums/[albumsId]`
- there will be an **API which gets album details by albumID**, it will check if album exists,
  if not then return Not Found error & show some UI(message), else just
  show details.
- This way you can handle that randomID in just 1 API call rather than
  2 API calls.

> ***If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer if necessary)***

Comment: Isnt this what im doing though? In my middleware im calling the api I created prior to get existing albums, I then check if the album they are trying to get to exists, and if not, returns an error

Comment: @gj-dev On `/albums/album1` this page, do you have an API which gets details of `album1`  ?

Comment: @Beast90K no not yet, as of right now im just trying to figure out how to make albums that dont exist not accessible. The API I had perviously created just fetches all existing albums from the users document

Comment: thanks for the help! I realized what you had meant and got it working through that idea